# How to move my command in the same section of copy/paste menu?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-extensions, vsix, vspackage

I need a little bit of help to move my command in the same section of copy/paste (context menu).

[image]

I tried to copy the parenting of Copy command that can be found in ShellCmdPlace.vsct without success.

```
  <Group guid="guidSHLMainMenu" id="IDG_VS_CTXT_CMDWIN_CUTCOPY" priority="0x0100">
    <Parent guid="guidSHLMainMenu" id="IDM_VS_CTXT_COMMANDWINDOW"/>
  </Group>
```

The only thing that I modified in my vsct file to obtain the result of the screenshot is the parent id of my menuGroup:

```
<Groups>
    <Group guid="guidCommand1PackageCmdSet" id="MyMenuGroup" priority="0x0500">
        <Parent guid="guidSHLMainMenu" id="IDM_VS_CTXT_CODEWIN"/>
    </Group>
</Groups>
```

Thanks!

Comment: May I know if you have got any chance to check my answer? I am glad to help if you have any others questions.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a menu group, as you apparently want to add your menu item (aka command) to the same menu group that the Cut, Copy, and Paste already belong to.

What you want to do here is parent your command to the already existing menu group. guidSHLMainMenu | IDG_VS_CTXT_CMDWIN_CUTCOPY.

Sincerely,

Answer (score 0):

You can go to Tools > Customize and find this in Context menu in Commands tag:
[image]

Then find your command and use Move Up or Move Down to move it:
[image]